# OpenApi Spec - What is the best practice that multiple microservices use the same schema (data model)

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

OpenApi Spec - What is the best practice that multiple microservices use the same components schema (data model) ?

Example:

**Microservice1 api spec:**

```
responses:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyResponse' 

components:
   schemas:
     MyResponse:
         type: object
         required:
            true
         properties:
            myvariable1:
                   type: string
            myvariable2:
                   type: string
```

**Microservice2 api spec:**

responses:
$ref: '#/components/schemas/MyResponse'

```
components:
   schemas:
     MyResponse:
         type: object
         required:
            true
         properties:
            myvariable1:
                   type: string
            myvariable2:
                   type: string
```

Is there any way that both microservices 1 and 2 can used the components schema from a centralized place? so that consistency can be maintained among both microservices?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Swagger Documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) it is possible to use three types of syntax when using `$ref`:

1. **Local Reference**: `$ref: '#/components/schemas/MyResponse'`. In this notation the `#` character denotes the document root.
2. **Remote Reference**: `$ref: 'document.json#/MyResponse'`. Reference other documents in the same folder or in relation to the folder.
3. **URL Reference**: `$ref: 'http://myservice.tld/components/schemas/definition.json#/MyResponses'`. Here you can reference schemas on an entirely different server.

The exact *best practice* depends on how you are using your OpenAPI specification in Spring Boot, there are different ways to automatically generate API definitions (with `@ControllerAdvice`, `@Operation`, `springdoc-openapi`, JSR-303 Bean Validation, ...).